# Animating border SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, graphics

Please see this codepen: https://codepen.io/MRDJR97/pen/LLbPNZ

It is a SVG shape with a dashed border.
How do I make all the lines transparent/invisible except for one?

code:

html:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="340px" height="333px" viewBox="0 0 340 333" enable-background="new 0 0 340 333" xml:space="preserve">
```

css:

```
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 50;
  stroke-dashoffset: 10;
  animation: dash 6s linear alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```